# ASP.NET MVC 5 : Binding all the partial views to the main controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web app using ASP.NET MVC 5. I have multiple partial views and their corresponding models, but only one controller corresponding to the main view, that uses below code to display each of the partial views.

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewName");}
```

My question is, how do I pass the form data from all the partial views (including the main view) to the main controller?

Initially, when I added only 1 partial view, I added it's model as a parameter to the main controller's `public ActionResult Index(MainModelName model1, PartialModelName pmodel1)`. and that worked fine and I could access the data from the partial view in the main controller.

But, when I added the 2nd partial view and updated the `public ActionResult Index(...)` with an additional partial model parameter, it didn't help, as in the data is not being passed from the partial view to the main controller. though I don't get any error.

My main model class has the object references of the partial models as its data members. From what I read, I need to have a list of models as a parameter to the method in the main controller, but my models are not sub-types.

What's the idiomatic way of handling such a situation?

Thank you!

EDIT1 : Here's the code for a sample app, I get null reference error while accessing `mainModel.PartialModel2.Pm2` in MainController.cs, while I can access `mainModel.PartialModel1.Pm1` properly.

**MainModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestApp.Models
{
    public class MainModel
    {
        private int mm1;
        private PartialModel1 partialModel1;
        private PartialModel2 partialModel2;

        public int Mm1 { get => mm1; set => mm1 = value; }
        public PartialModel1 PartialModel1 { get => partialModel1; set => partialModel1 = value; }
        public PartialModel2 PartialModel2 { get => partialModel2; set => partialModel2 = value; }
    }
}
```

**PartialModel1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestApp.Models
{
    public class PartialModel1
    {
        private int pm1;

        public PartialModel1()
        {
        }

        public int Pm1 { get => pm1; set => pm1 = value; }
    }
}
```

**PartialModel2.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestApp.Models
{
    public class PartialModel2
    {
        private int pm2;

        public PartialModel2()
        {
        }

        public int Pm2 { get => pm2; set => pm2 = value; }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model TestApp.Models.MainModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>MainModel</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mm1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mm1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mm1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial1", Model);  }
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial2", Model);  }
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                    }

    @*<div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>*@
</body>
</html>
```

**Partial1.cshtml**

```
@model TestApp.Models.MainModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MainModel")) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>PartialModel1</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartialModel1.Pm1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartialModel1.Pm1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartialModel1.Pm1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @*<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>*@
    </div>
}

@*<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>*@
```

**Partial2.cshtml**

```
@model TestApp.Models.MainModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MainModel")) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>PartialModel2</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartialModel2.Pm2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartialModel2.Pm2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartialModel2.Pm2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @*<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>*@
    </div>
}

@*<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>*@
```

**MainController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestApp.Models;

namespace TestApp.Controllers
{
    public class MainController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Main

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(MainModel mainModel)
        {
            //Access mainModel.PartialModel1.Pm1
            //Access mainModel.PartialModel2.Pm2 

            string msg = mainModel.PartialModel1.Pm1 + " " + mainModel.PartialModel2.Pm2;
            ViewBag.message = msg;


            return View("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: If I just keep it `@{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial2");  }`, I get this error - `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TestApp.Models.Main', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'TestApp.Models.Partial2'.`

**MainController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestApp.Models;

namespace TestApp.Controllers
{
    public class MainController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Main

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new Main() { Partial1 = new Partial1(), Partial2 = new Partial2() });

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Main mainModel)
        {
            //Access mainModel.PartialModel1.Pm1
            //Access mainModel.PartialModel2.Pm2            

            string msg = mainModel.Partial1.Pm1 + " " + mainModel.Partial2.Pm2;
            ViewBag.message = msg;

            return View("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestApp.Models
{
    public class Main
    {
        public int Mm1 { get; set; }
        public Partial1 Partial1 { get; set; }
        public Partial2 Partial2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Partial1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestApp.Models
{
    public class Partial1
    {
        public Partial1()
        {
        }
        public int Pm1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Partial2.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestApp.Models
{
    public class Partial2
    {
        public Partial2()
        {
        }
        public int Pm2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model TestApp.Models.Main

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>MainModel</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mm1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mm1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mm1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>               

            </div>

            @{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial2");  }
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial1");  }

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                    }

    @*<div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>*@
</body>
</html>
```

**Partial1.cshtml**

```
@model TestApp.Models.Partial1


@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>PartialModel1</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pm1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pm1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pm1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


</div>


@*<div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>*@
```

**Partial2.cshtml**

```
@model TestApp.Models.Partial2


@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>PartialModel2</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pm2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pm2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pm2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@*<div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>*@
```

Comment: Pass model to your partial view? `@{Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewName", Model);}`

Comment: Thanks for your response. but, I want to access the form data of the partial views in my main controller, and not render the partial views with data.

Comment: We need more information please provide relevant code on your `main` and `partial` form. etc. Normally you would do what I mentioned above and pass in your `ViewModel` then you would be able to access it from your `controller`

Comment: you want to access the data on HttpPost?

Comment: I don't know if it's the idiomatic way but you can use a global viewmodel composing all partiel view viewmodels. MVC can recompose the global ViewModel if the input data names are prefixed with the partial view viewmodel name in the global viewmodel class.

Comment: @12seconds: correct me if I'm wrong, isn't @{Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewName", Model);} used to pass data to the partial view?

Comment: @akerra Yes, on a HttpPost.

Comment: It doesn't just do that, when you submit (`POST`) and in your `controller` you have `Index(MainViewModel model)`, you would have w/e the value you put on your `PartialView`

Comment: @RomainDeneau, I believe that's what I have done. though I didn't get this part "if the input data names are prefixed with the partial view viewmodel name in the global viewmodel class". Also, by viewmodel, you mean the model class, right?

Comment: If you are form posting then just put the correct url in the form's attributes and that form will post to the specified action.  Presumably each form does something different so each form will have a matching action in the controller.  I would probably make view models for each and then wrap them up in the main view but that is just my preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of stuff here you should change.  For starters, you don't need to use the form of getter you're using.

Instead of

```
private int pm1;
public int Pm1 { get => pm1; set => pm1 = value; }
```

You only have to have this:

```
public int Pm1 { get; set; }
```

You don't need the private backing variable.

You only need to populate the get and set methods if you are going to actually provide methods that do something.

Second, you need to instantiate the PartialModel's. It doesn't matter a lot in this case, since you are not referencing any actual data, just metadata.. but as soon as you add real data it can cause issues.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new MainModel() { PartialModel1 = new PartialModel1(), PartialModel2 = new PartialModel2 });
}
```

Next, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this, but it's probably not what you think it's doing:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MainModel"))
```

What you have here is nested forms, and that's not legal HTML.

Instead, you should remove the forms from the partials, even if it would be legal then a form will only submit the data within that form.  This is your main problem.

also, remove the submit buttons in the partials.  Just have the one over-arching form and submit button in the Index.cshtml.

Comment: Thanks! I made all the changes you suggested. But I get this error -
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object at this line in the MainController.cs `string msg = mainModel.PartialModel1.Pm1 + " " + mainModel.PartialModel2.Pm2;`

Comment: I also had to change `@{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial2", Model);  }
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial1", Model);  }` to `@{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial2", Model.PartialModel2);  }
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial1", Model.PartialModel1);  }`

Comment: @user7413 - specifying the submodel will not generate the correct naming conventions for model binding.  You will need to specify just Model.  In fact, you don't have to specify Model at all, Model is the default if you omit it.  You're getting an null reference exception because you are rendering the partials with the submodel.  Unfortunately, now that your code has deviated from what's posted, I can't tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I will post my updated code soon. By the way, What is the way to pass submodel objects to the main controller? how is it done usually?

Comment: @user7413 - you don't have to, because the RenderPartial renders all the code into the same parent page.  This is why passing the submodel the partial doesn't work correctly, because when you actually post it's in the parent pages context.  Thus, all models have to be referenced from MainModel.

Comment: I'm very new to C# & ASP.NET, so I don't quite get what changes I need to make? Could you please tell the code changes?

Comment: @user7413 - I gave you the code in my post.  Doing just what I said should work, but you made additional changes that I did not say, and messed it up again.

Comment: I'm sorry, but It did'nt work, I had to change `@{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial2", Model); } @{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial1", Model); }` to `@{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial2", Model.Partial2); } @{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial1", Model.Partial1); }` because I was getting an error - The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TestApp.Models.Main', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'TestApp.Models.Partial2'.

Comment: That's because you changed the @model types in the Partial models between your first set of code and your current code, something I didn't tell you to do.  Looking at your updated code.  Change the @model types for the partials back to MainModel.  Remove the model passing from the RenderPartial.  And change your helpers to include the model.. Ie. `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Partial1.pm1, ...)` .  Looks like you also changed the name of the MainModel to Main... so adjust for that as well

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked :-) I also got to learn something new! Thanks again!

Comment: @user7413 - the real thing you should learn is to not make additional changes while debugging.  Otherwise you break other things even though the original problem may have been solved.. but you attribute it to the original problem.

Comment: True that! Thanks for the lesson and your time :-) I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code:

```
public ActionResult Index(MainModelName model1, PartialModelName pmodel1)
```

To

```
public ActionResult Index(NewMainModelName  newModel)
```

In class NewMainModelName  you can woke like this:

```
   public class NewMainModelName
    {
        public MainModelName model1 { get; set; }
        public PartialModelName pmodel1{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Or I could just change it to public ActionResult Index(MainModelName model1) ?